# htaccess redirect based on cookie value

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

I have searched around Google for a while and have not been able to find a solution.

I need to redirect users of my site to a welcome page only if they havent visited the site before.

I am going to store a hasVisited cookie and redirect if this is false and set it on the welcome page.

I can get this working in PHP and jQuery but when it checks to see if the cookie is set it loads the default page content first and then redirects. Doesnt look too go.

What I am after is:
a - Will using htaccess stop the default page loading first before the redirect
b - How to do the above

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do cookie checking with PHP and then call header("Location: http://your-url.com/") to redirect them

i.e.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['hasVisited']) {
    header("Location: http://example.com/welcome.php");
}
```

Be warned this will effect SEO - Google will only be able to check the welcome page for every php file you put this in. You can add this to allow google through the check

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['hasVisited'] && !strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],"Googlebot"))
```

Comment: OK. So just keep using PHP. Cool

Comment: op should do this before printing anything. Otherwise will return warning and present content which is not desirable

Comment: Yes, as jribeiro mentioned this needs to be at the top - since we are sending headers

Comment: (i) The way this is worded implies that using PHP is the only approach. not true.  (ii) You need to add this intercept to every PHP script. (iii) you are missing the `Status: 301` header which you also should emit. (iv) why aren't you maintaining the original request context and passing it to welcome.php?

Comment: (iii) Status 301 implies the URL has forever been changed, and that the resource you are going to is the correct URL for what you're trying to access. This is not the case here.
(iv) Because the original request was for a page other than welcome
(ii) This doesn't seem to be that big of a problem, since that was what the OP was doing anyway
(i) see reply to (ii)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use PHP.  You can simply use a rewrite rule.  How you maintain the previous context depends on whether you use SEO optimised encoding or traditional parameter encoding for your parameters.  So

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond   %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !\bhasVisited=       [NC]
RewriteRule   (?:!welcome\.php\b)(?=\.php\b)(.*)  welcome.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The first bit of the rule is to prevent it firing twice.  The second limits this to php scripts (you don't want CSS used by welcome.php to be redirected as well). You also need to store the initial URI just in case the visitor wants to continue with his or her initial request.

This approach is simpler than the alternative PHP check -- which would of course need to be added to every script.